# Selenium stuck on local mp4 file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I use selenium to display local media files (png,jpg,gif,mp4) for 5 seconds in the browser.

Everything work like a charm except when I encounter a mp4 file. The driver open and show the mp4 file (play it without any issue) and then get stuck on it. Those are small mp4 file (1,700 KB).

I tryed setting up a driver.implicitly_wait(5) but its look like the driver is still receving data so no timeout.

relevant code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

for item in r.json()['data']:
    path = find_images(item)
    driver_path = os.path.abspath(path)
    driver.get('file:///{}'.format(driver_path))
    sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is total time of your mp4 video? if your selenium script stucks while playing video file, then run it as 'Process'.